# Angular 6 - Use a function from child component

Tags: javascript, angular, function, ionic-framework

I'm programming an App and my problem is in **Angular 6** and **Ionic framework**.

I have a parent component with 4 child "pages" (components). I want to call the `scrollToTop()` function in the child component, to scroll the page to the top.

TabsPage offers 4 Buttons (like on Instagram where you can navigate trough the app).

Parent component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Tab1Page } from '../tab1/tab1.page';
import { Tab2Page } from '../tab2/tab2.page';
import { Tab3Page } from '../tab3/tab3.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild(Tab1Page) tab1: Tab1Page;
  @ViewChild(Tab2Page) tab2: Tab2Page;
  @ViewChild(Tab3Page) tab3: Tab3Page;

  up2(){
    this.tab2.scroll2();
  }

  up3(){
    this.tab3.scroll3();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-tabs>

    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab1" (click)='up1()'>
            <ion-label>Tab1</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" (click)='up2()'>
            <ion-label>Tab2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3" (click)='up3()'>
            <ion-label>Tab3</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab4" (click)='up4()'>
            <ion-label>Tab 4</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

    </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Child Component (Tab3):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {
  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

  scroll3(){
    this.content.scrollToTop(0);
  }
}
```

This is the Error code:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroll3' of undefined

Comment: Maybe make the function public? Or extract the scroll logic?

Comment: when do you call `up3`? (seems your tab3 is undefined in that time, either because of timing, or because `Tab3Page` doesn't exists)

Comment: Please show your 'tabs.page.html'.   '@ViewChild(Tab3Page) tab3: Tab3Page;'  does not seem to work.

Comment: `ViewChild` is only available (for sure) on `AfterViewInit` and after that. Consider @RezaRahmati comment on where are you calling that.
Another thing, what if you change your `ViewChild` to `@ViewChild('tab3') tab3: Tab3Component`.

Comment: why not call such scroll top method inside child components lifecycle hook ?